# excel vba permutations exceed 1048576 rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a permutation list in excel for 6 numbers, each in their own columnA-F and each number is from 1-38. when i run the VBA i find that the permutations far exceed rows 1048576 available in excel, so therefore the VBA ends at that point. i want a VBA that when the rows reach 1048576 on whatever sheet and the permutation isnt finished it will just create a new sheet and continue where it stopped on the previous sheet and automatically create sheets until the permutation ends. i've searched passed questions but none found to help. Any expert help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
   Sub Perm()

   Dim a As Integer
   Dim b As Integer
   Dim c As Integer
   Dim d As Integer
   Dim e As Integer
   Dim f As Integer

    n = 1

For a = 1 To 38
For b = 1 To 38
    For c = 1 To 38
        For d = 1 To 38
            For e = 1 To 38
                For f = 1 To 38
Cells(n, 1).Value = a
        Cells(n, 2).Value = b
                Cells(n, 3).Value = c
                        Cells(n, 4).Value = d
                                Cells(n, 5).Value = e
                                        Cells(n, 6).Value = f

                n = n + 1


                Next f
            Next e
        Next d
      Next c
    Next b
  Next a

 End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, I'm going to ask the obvious question here: *why???*

Comment: And do you have any idea how long this all take to run?  (Hint: it will be a very ... Long ... Time ...)

Comment: If your doing this for a lottery thing, then you want combinations, not permutations. In permutations the order matters (e.g. 123 is different than 321) but with combinations the order doesn't matter (e.g. 123 is the same as 321).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett, i'm new to VBA and i just thought hey why not try this to get my feet wet? secondly, havn't you experienced the excel row limitation problem 1048576?

Comment: @EStraka, i never thought of combinations, interesting thought. Thank you.

Comment: @chrisneilsen, time is irrelevant when gaining knowledge is the main objective

Comment: @YungKing as a learning exercise, fair enough.  When I say a long time, it will likely take _days_.  The lesson here is that referencing the worksheet inside a long loop is very slow, and there are ways to avoid that. I won't spoil the fun by providing an answer, but hint: look up Variant Array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
Sub Perm()

Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim d As Integer
Dim e As Integer
Dim f As Integer
Dim n As Long

Dim maxRows As Long
Dim sheetNumber As Integer
Dim loopCounter As Integer

 maxRows = 1048576
 loopCounter = 38

 sheetNumber = 1
 n = 1

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet-" & sheetNumber

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For a = 1 To loopCounter
For b = 1 To loopCounter
    For c = 1 To loopCounter
        For d = 1 To loopCounter
            For e = 1 To loopCounter
                For f = 1 To loopCounter


                  Cells(n, 1).Value = a
                  Cells(n, 2).Value = b
                  Cells(n, 3).Value = c
                  Cells(n, 4).Value = d
                  Cells(n, 5).Value = e
                  Cells(n, 6).Value = f

                  If n = maxRows Then
                       sheetNumber = sheetNumber + 1
                       ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
                       ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet-" & sheetNumber
                       n = 0
                  End If

                  n = n + 1

                Next f
            Next e
        Next d
      Next c
    Next b
  Next a

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

This will create a sheet called "Sheet-1" and fill it up down to row 1048576. 
Then it will create a new sheet called "Sheet-2" and repeat until that is full, etc.

It is best to disable `ScreenUpdating` for intensive cell writing as it will make a big reduction to the running time.

Good luck, as it will probably take awhile. As the other poster says, it will need nearly 3000 worksheets. Hopefully you have enough memory on your machine.

Comment: how do i pause the program to see how much has been completed, then resume it when ready. Presently, the code is running but i don't see any numbers being generated, so i can't really confirm if its doing what its suppose to do. Secondly, what does "If n Mod maxRows = 0" mean?

Comment: why does the program start at sheet-1? it totally omits already existing sheet1.

Comment: If you press `ctrl-break`, this should stop the code so that you can see what value `n` has. Regards `n Mod maxRows`, have a look at online help for the Mod function, you could also use `if n = maxRows` instead; it's just a personal preference.  My answer does not assume any knowledge of your existing workbook, which is why the method only accesses sheets that it creates; feel free to modify to suit your needs.